# InputStream returning NullPointerException (Java)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, inputstream

Here is the code that is getting the NullPointerException error:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("twentyone.txt");
InputStreamReader iz=new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(iz);
```

What could be going wrong?

*Edit: the printStackTrace

```
03-19 18:20:18.662: E/AndroidRuntime(929): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Edit 2: Code till the exception:

```
public class ListViewAa3 extends ListViewA{



public String[] process(String cti)throws IOException{
    String ctid=cti;
    Log.d("Outside try invoked","tag1");
    try{
        Log.d("beginning of try invoked","tag2");
        try{
    InputStream is = getAssets().open("USCOUNTIES.txt");
    InputStreamReader iz=new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(iz);}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: `getAssets()` could be null

Comment: how to solve that? my assets folder has the said file..

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more code, but first find out if `getAssets()` is indeed null by using a debugger or looking at the stack trace. Then find out why it is null.

Comment: please give full code

Comment: That stack trace doesn't help us in telling you where it is, we need more than that. That said I'm betting `getAssets()` is null.

Comment: @Biswajit Added in the edit.

Comment: @LoganDam The error is in the InputStream line as I put log.d() above and below it, and the below one doesn't get displayed in logcat.

Comment: see also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14433232/1288408

Comment: what is your getAssets()? check it is null or not

Comment: I am pretty sure `getAssets()` is null. I'd expect `open()` to throw some kind of IOException if there were a problem with the file name.

Comment: @KatjaChristiansen Maybe it is, how to correct that...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I got it. I had to pass the context of the main activity to this class, then use `context.getAssets.open("twentyone.txt");`

To anyone who has the same problem, do this:
Put this in the onCreate function of the class with activity:
 `Context context=getApplicationContext();`

Pass context to the new class's function(in my case "process(String a,Context context)")
Then type this in the process function:

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("twentyone.txt");
```

Took me 4 hours to figure such a silly thing out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `getAssets()` is null and try to Check whether file twentyone.txt exists , if it exists then try to enter the full file path and re-run your application !

Comment: the file exists. maybe getAssets() is null.. How to correct that? I am coding for android BTW.

Answer (score -1):

The file that you open has not the full path, that's why the error. Try

```
new File("twentyone.txt").getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: open stream using absolute file name

Comment: great, then you must define it